# Imagelist cf.net and .net designer problem

Tags: .net, designer, imagelist, compact-framework

After some testing, I found out that streaming of ImageList using CF WinForms designer is different from streaming using WinForms designer.
If images are added using cf.net designer and form is reopened using winfrorms designer an exception "Method 'System.Windows.Forms.Design.ImageListDesigner+OriginalImageCollection.Add' not found. " is raised.

Is there any option to change default streaming or any custom ImageList from some other provider (3-party) that can be used in both designers?

Any other recommended solution?

Answer (score 0):

How about not filling the image list at design time, but adding the images from program resources at runtime?

Comment: then I have to deploy images too. Also I lose designtime support

Comment: Well, you implicitly deploy the images in either case. In one case, they are "embedded" in your form, in the case I suggest, they are embedded resources. In both cases, you don't have to deploy separate files!